# Open EOG preferences panel on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, eog

This is a very odd one for me. I just installed a new system under ubuntu 18.04, and with it the last version of eog.
I want to remove the automatic filtering when zooming it, and I know it is in the preferences panel.

I definitely spent too much time trying to open this panel. Where is it on the new interface?

[image: New Interface]

Comment: Next to `Activities` in the top left of your screen? Click on `Image Viewer`. But I don't see anything about automatic filtering there.

Comment: Inder "Image view" tab, "smooth images when zoomed out"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the dropdown menu next to Activities in the top left of the screen. Select Preferences. Uncheck the "Smooth images ..." options.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to first open an image using `Image Viewer` or using the command

```
eog filename
```

Then right-click on the `Image Viewer` icon, and then select "Preferences"

[image]